# Как определить, какие дескрипторы существуют у стороннего приложения?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, тестирование

Доброго времени суток!

Во время тестирования, проявилась проблема, что сервер сжирает всю виртуальную память через несколько суток работы. Самое подозрительное, что смог заметить, это бешенное количество открытых дескрипторов, которое достигает порядка 500000 штук через неделю работы, а это около 1.7Гб файла подкачки, при этом диспетчер задач показывает адекватные цифры по занятой памяти (около 100Мб занятой и 170Мб выделенной)

Т.е. проблема, как мне кажется, в немерянном количестве открытых дескрипторов. Знаю про process explorer, который идёт в комплекте sysinternals, но он показывает только порядка 100-200 дескрипторов, а где все остальные? Как бы отловить этих зависших и не освобожденных нигодяев?

Ps: сейчас запустил стресстест с мониторингом сервера раз в 15 секунд на количество дескрипторов (autoit и powershell), завтра буду логи смотреть, но что-то подсказывает, что провала не будет, и где-то в другом месте программы они текут. Если бы можно было бы узнать, что за дескрипторы залипли, это бы очень сократило время поиска проблемы.

Есть ли другие любые способы отловить утечку?

Pps: не знаю какие теги прилепить к вопросу...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем с проблемой непосредственно утечки разобрались-локализовали, нашли частный случай, когда она себя проявляет.

Но вопрос хочу пока оставить открытым. Диспетчер задач показывает количество дескрипторов. Их можно также легко узнать powershell или c# через processinfo.handlecount, но более подробно о них ничего не нашёл.

Может есть какие-то апи виндовские, которые могут показать более подробную информацию о дескриптора приложения?

**Обновление**

Это количество, которое я и так через диспетчер задач виндовский вижу... Хотелось бы более подробно по найденному хендлу (не знаю как найти) узнать что за объект (хотя бы класс объекта).
например processExplorer показывает названия файлов, хэндлы TCP соединений, и т.д... Но он показал из 100к хэндлов только штук 100... т.е. остальное где-то болталось, но ссылка интересная, на пару ссылок в глубь зашел и уже кое-что полезное узнал. Спасибо, нужно там покопаться...

Comment: @pincher1519, в винде не пишу, но это ([GetProcessHandleCount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683214%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) случайно не то, что Вы ищете?

Answer (score 0):

Под линуксом можно посмотреть в /proc/PidOfProcess/fd/ все открытые дескрипторы.